# Swing JTextField text changed listener DocumentListener infinity loop

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, jtextfield, documentlistener

Okay I've a problem with a swing event listener... Short introduction I develop a Java application with a Swing UI structured by the MVC pattern.

- MyView -> The text is changed by the user and the view should inform model by controller
- MyModel -> Store the data and inform view about changes through controller
- MyController -> Interface used to inform model and view about changes

Based on this classes model and view are only connected through the controller class. The view class contains a text field for user input which should update the model class with the user input **without** pressing a button. This means I need a listener for JTextField that waits for user input/change of text...

I tried `DocumentListener` but it doesn't work, a exception is thrown: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to mutate in notification`

I think the problem here is that the model class called also the controller if properties changed and the controller informs/changes the view again -> Result: Infinity loop

Both solutions I found didn't work for me:

[Swing JTextField on text change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351878/swing-jtextfield-on-text-change)

[JTextField listener when text changes that modifies textField's text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303695/jtextfield-listener-when-text-changes-that-modifies-textfields-text)

**MyModel.java**

```
public void setHost(String host) // Method called by controller to change model
{
    String oldHost = this.host;
    this.host = host;

    this.firePropertyChange("Host", oldHost, this.host); // Model inform view about changes
}
```

**MyView.java**

```
@Override public void modelPropertyChange(final PropertyChangeEvent event)
{
    // Method used to update view and called by controller

    if(event.getPropertyName().equals("Username"))
    {
        String username = (String) event.getNewValue();
        this.nameField.setText(username);
    }
}
```

The problem is when the document listener is called because the user input something the model is changed call the property changed method of view and view replace the text with the same text which raise again a document changed event and the listener is called... Infinity loop

I tried to work with an `ActionListener` it works fine but it is necessary for the user to press return to assign the changes... *Are there any other options to listen for text changes in a JTextField without `DocumentListener`? Or what should I changed by my MVC pattern to solve this issue?*

**EDIT**

I tried the solution of *Peter Walser* but a new exception was thrown:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.x1c1b.carrierpigeon.service.mvc.AbstractController.setModelProperty(AbstractController.java:62)
at org.x1c1b.carrierpigeon.desktop.ui.controller.LoginController.changeUsername(LoginController.java:12)
at org.x1c1b.carrierpigeon.desktop.ui.view.LoginView$UsernameChangedListener.updateFieldState(LoginView.java:221)
at org.x1c1b.carrierpigeon.desktop.ui.view.LoginView$UsernameChangedListener.insertUpdate(LoginView.java:203)
at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.fireInsertUpdate(AbstractDocument.java:201)
at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.handleInsertString(AbstractDocument.java:748)
at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.insertString(AbstractDocument.java:707)
at javax.swing.text.PlainDocument.insertString(PlainDocument.java:130)
at org.x1c1b.carrierpigeon.desktop.ui.util.TextFieldLimit.insertString(TextFieldLimit.java:26)
at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.replace(AbstractDocument.java:669)
at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.replaceSelection(JTextComponent.java:1328)
at javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit$DefaultKeyTypedAction.actionPerformed(DefaultEditorKit.java:884)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1668)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2882)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2929)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2845)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6316)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:835)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1103)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:974)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:800)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4760)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to mutate in notification
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.writeLock(AbstractDocument.java:1338)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.replace(AbstractDocument.java:658)
    at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.setText(JTextComponent.java:1669)
    at org.x1c1b.carrierpigeon.desktop.ui.view.LoginView.modelPropertyChange(LoginView.java:76)
    at org.x1c1b.carrierpigeon.service.mvc.AbstractController.propertyChange(AbstractController.java:47)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:327)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:263)
    at org.x1c1b.carrierpigeon.service.mvc.AbstractModel.firePropertyChange(AbstractModel.java:27)
    at org.x1c1b.carrierpigeon.desktop.ui.model.LoginModel.setUsername(LoginModel.java:39)
    ... 52 more
```

It seems like the document of `JTextField` is still locked during inform the model, because it calls the method `setText` the exception is thrown and this operation is illegal but I can't figure out why?!

**EDIT**

For now I solved this bug by the instructions and the first solution of **Peter Walser** combined with executing the instructions set by the `DocumentListener` on the EDT!

Comment: @camickr Yea sure but I didn't try to filter the text... It isn't intended that the text in the text field is changed while user is typing... The model inform/change the text in the `JTextField` each time when it changed itself because there is a second controller which changes the model by data of a socket... So it is necessary that the model can change the JTextField text, but in this special case when the user and not the socket change the JTextField text than it isn't intended that the model change the view again...

Comment: `I tried the solution of Peter Walser` - Peter suggested two solutions. We don't know which one you tried? I would use the first approach. `but I got a new exception:...` - a solution has already been given on how to avoid that problem. Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem so we don't have to guess what you are doing. That is all you need is a JFrame with a text field and a button. The user can type text into the text field to update the model. The button will add text directly to the model.  Then maybe we can help debug.

Comment: @camickr Also thank you for your time I solved it with the first solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches to properly solve this:

### Fire a property change event only if actually something changed

There's **no point in notifying** if the property **value is the same as before** (not changed at all). Avoiding the unnecessary event will effectively break your loop:

```
public void setHost(String host) {
  // check if property actually changed
  if (Objects.equals(this.host, host) return;
  String oldHost = this.host;
  this.host = host;
  this.firePropertyChange("Host", oldHost, this.host); 
}
```

or (fancy compact form):

```
public void setHost(String host) {
    if (!Objects.equals(this.host, host)) {
        firePropertyChange("Host", this.host, this.host=host);
    }
}
```

### Do one-way synchronization to avoid cascades

*Changing a propery in the model can change a property in the view can change a property in the model can change...* - this can quickly run in circles.

To break these cascades, do a one-way synchronization: 
**while the model notifies the view about changes, ignore any cascading updates.**

To do so, you need a flag on the controller (in your case, the view holding the microcontrollers a.k.a. Swing listeners):

**MyView.java**:

```
boolean updating;

@Override public void modelPropertyChange(final PropertyChangeEvent event)
{
    if (updating) {
        // cascading update, ignore
        return;
    }
    updating=true;
    try {
        if(event.getPropertyName().equals("Username")) {
        {
            String username = (String) event.getNewValue();
            this.nameField.setText(username);
        }
        ...
    }
    finally {
        updating=false;
    }
}
```

The first approach is pretty straightforward (but can get complicated when dealing with complex objects and collections).
The second approach is easy and more forgiving by design - view always represents model (no changes missed), and cascading updates are blocked.

Comment: I tried your solutions but I got a new exception: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to mutate in notification`... I will update the question maybe you could take a look at it...

Comment: updated the answer, it even got simpler: cascading updates while updating can be prevented without having to check the 'update' flag in the listeners. should solve the 'mutate in notification' issue as well :)

Comment: It doesn't work I can't figure out how to fix this holy shit :), I debugged it and the problem is the `setText` call in the `@Override public void modelPropertyChange(final PropertyChangeEvent event)` method called by the changed model... The origin of the stack trace is the same as before...

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time! Your first solution with the modification of the model solved this issue... I prevent the solved exception by executing the code for informing the model explicit on the EDT and your solution prevent the infinity loop thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In your PropertyChangeListener for the "Username" property you could:

1. remove the `DocumentListener` from the text field
2. update the text field
3. add the `DocumentListener` back to the text field.

> I tried DocumentListener but it doesn't work, a exception is thrown: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to mutate in notification

For information only, to get rid of that message you can wrap the code in a Swing utilities.invokeLater() so the code is executed after the listener code is finished executing. Although I think you will still get your infinite loop.

Comment: Yea the problem is that not `JTextField` as widget is registered as listener for PropertyChangeListener instead the whole class `MyView` is connected with the controller class and the method `@Override public void modelPropertyChange(final PropertyChangeEvent event)` handle all other widgets too... So it isn't possible in an easy way to remove the listener

Comment: @0x1C1B, I guess I wasn't clear, you need to remove the DocumentListener from the text field, not the PropertyListener. Then when the text field is updated via the PropertyChangeEvent you won't notify the model of the change again so you don't have your loop.

Comment: Oh okay that makes more sense thank you I will try it